# Script fails while sending text using Keyboard.Sendkeys or .Text syntaxt in VSTS 2013

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests, sendkeys

```
txtAgency.Text = "test";
```

> Error - PlaybackFailureException was unhanlded by user code. An
>   exception of type
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.PlaybackFailureException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll but was not
>   handled in user code

Details:

1. Tool - VS 2013
2. IE - IE10
3. The same code works fine in VS2010 but while running on VS 2013 this happens.
4. Running on VDI
5. Works fine at times but fails most of the times. Works fine in 2010.
6. Sends the keys as "ttteeesst". pattern keeps changing but output is failure.

Workaround tried:

1. Checked both true and false for
   Playback.PlaybackSettings.SendKeysAsScanCode
2. Checked sendkeysdelay = 1000;

Comment: Does this happen every time you run your playback in VS2013?  I've noticed the same behavior some times, but it usually works on the 2nd attempt through for some reason.

Comment: @RyanCox -  yes most of the times it happens. There is no specific pattern observed why and when it fails. The issue didnt happen on running same code in VS2010 with IE8 version. Later got the erroron VS2013 with IE9&10. Got it running now in **'IE11'** . Hope this will not happen again.